# Can we run multiple java versions in parallel for different purposes?

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, java-11

I am using Elasticsearch which uses Java 8. I also want to install kafka on the same machine but kafka uses java 11. Both services are to be run in parallel. Can anyone tell how can I run both java versions at same time?

Comment: Yes, you can install multiple versions of Java on the same machine and run different applications with different versions.

Comment: This is where docker containerization fits the need

Comment: @jesper How to do it? Any idea? I don't want to use docker

Comment: You didn't say which operating system you are using. Different OSes have different options and tools available. For instance, there's `jenv` for macOS which I highly recommend when you need to use multiple different java versions for development. On linux, `/etc/alternatives` is often used (or at least was): https://askubuntu.com/questions/484561/what-is-etc-alternatives-used-for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Manually download and unpack Java

- https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11
- https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-17-lts&os=windows&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jre

2. Instead of simply starting java with the

- `java -args` commandline,
- you can start it via `/install/path/to/java/bin/java -args`
- or, for windows, use `C:\install\location\bin\java.exe -args`

You might want to make some start scripts / batch files for that, depending on the exact requirements of your system and Elasticsearch and kafka and possibly other software.

That's it.

### one little addition:

If you can **NOT** directly call java, or the software starts more java apps via the 'default' java, you can also use scripts to manipulate the *PATH* variables of your system before starting the app. Then you (and your apps) can simply call `java -args` again.

Answer (score 1):

Once you download different versions of JRE(java runtime environment) to your local, if you use [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/) IDE, you can checkout  different projects in single workspace & specify `Java Build Path` with JRE version you want.

This way, you can run multiple applications having different versions of Java.
I think other java IDEs also have this kind of support.

Comment: You can also easily install multiple JREs and simply configure each project separately. This way you do not even need different workspaces. You can also set multiple runtime configurations, so even the same project can be run with different JREs. But he's not talking about development, he's talking about running them as (system) services. So it's rather unlikely that he's starting them from Eclipse or any other IDE.